# Populate DataGridView by selecting any table from ComboBox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

This code is for combobox database tables.

```vb
Private Sub FillCombo_Sections()

    cmdAB = "SELECT Table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_name like 'Section%' or table_name like 'Title%' order by TABLE_NAME"
    'union() '--Select District--' order by dist_code"

    daAB = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdAB, cnn)
    dtAB = New DataTable()
    dsAB = New DataSet()
    daAB.Fill(dsAB, "information_schema.tables")
    dtAB = dsAB.Tables("information_schema.tables")

    SectionsComboBox.DataSource = dsAB.Tables("information_schema.tables")
    SectionsComboBox.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME"
    SectionsComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1
    SectionsComboBox.Text = "--- Select Section ---"

End Sub
```

This code is for datagridview load by selecting table name from combo box.

```vb
Private Sub dgv1LoadData()

    cmdA = (String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", Me.SectionsComboBox.SelectedValue))
    daA = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdA, cnn)
    dtA = New DataTable()
    dsA = New DataSet()
    daA.Fill(dsA, " " & SectionsComboBox.Text & " ")
    dtA = dsA.Tables("" & SectionsComboBox.Text & "")
    DGV1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    DGV1.DataSource = dtA

End Sub
```

[Select TableName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/japU3.jpg)

Comment: What is your question? (Hint: a question *always* ends with a `?`)

Comment: My question is that how to fill gridview by selecting table name from combobox

Comment: you could add ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged method and in the new sub you add your second fuction, of course you should check the index is bigger than -1

Comment: SelectedValue only works when you have the ValueMember property set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the below method for triggering the combo box selection and then call your function to load data

```
Private Sub SectionsComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SectionsComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted
    dgv1LoadData()
End Sub
```

Please change your FillCombo_Sections() as below. (Note that I have added the valueMember property)

```
Private Sub FillCombo_Sections()
    cmdAB = "SELECT Table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_name like 'Section%' or table_name like 'Title%' order by TABLE_NAME"
    'union() '--Select District--' order by dist_code"

    daAB = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdAB, cnn)
    dtAB = New DataTable()
    dsAB = New DataSet()
    daAB.Fill(dsAB, "information_schema.tables")
    dtAB = dsAB.Tables("information_schema.tables")

    SectionsComboBox.DataSource = dtAB
    SectionsComboBox.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME"
    SectionsComboBox.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME"
    SectionsComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1
    SectionsComboBox.Text = "--- Select Section ---"
End Sub
```

Then please change your dgv1LoadData() as below

```
Private Sub dgv1LoadData()
    cmdA = (String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", SectionsComboBox.Text))
    daA = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdA, cnn)
    dtA = New DataTable()
    daA.Fill(dtA)
    DGV1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    DGV1.DataSource = dtA
    DGV1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not helpful.

Comment: have used the following code for displaying names of sql db tables in combobox...now i want dat when i click on any of these table names from combo box..my dgv populates with that table's contents...i have gor three tables in my db..lol,datejoin and tble